# Tinylog Android, is it possible to clear the file?

Tags: java, file, logging, tinylog

I'm using the Tinylog library with the "rolling file" function to write logs to a file. Sometimes I need to clear a file.

Tried to do it with normal Java methods but it breaks the file and makes it hard to read.
Is there a way to clear the log file at any point so it doesn't break?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use standard [policies](https://tinylog.org/v2/configuration/#rolling-file-writer) for starting new log files at defined events. This is the recommended way.

If you need more flexibility, you can use the `DynamicPolicy` for starting a new log file programmatically. This policy is part of tinylog 2.5. The first milestone is expected to be released during this month and will include this new policy.

Configuration:

```
writer          = rolling file
writer.file     = foo.log
writer.policies = dynamic
```

Start new log file in Java:

```java
DynamicPolicy.setReset();
```

Comment: Hello again!

Android development.
Switched to version **2.5.0-M**. Started using DynamicNamePolicy. But ran into a problem:

`W/System.err: LOGGER ERROR: Failed creating service implementation 'org.tinylog.writers.RollingFileWriter' (java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid token 'tinylog.directory' in '#{tinylog.directory}/log_{date:yyyy -MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.txt')`

At the same time, version **2.4.1** works correctly. I checked on the Android presentation application and updated the version there. Same error.

Can you suggest what can be done?

Comment: Could you provide your full tinylog configuration? By the way, the `DynamicNamePolicy` was renamed into `DynamicPolicy ` and `dynamic name` into `dynamic` respectively.

Comment: Here is the complete config file:
[config](https://github.com/Gorbachew/presentations/blob/master/tinylog.properties)

I also tried to upgrade the version on this [example project](https://github.com/tinylog-org/tinylog-android-example) and got the same error

Comment: I could finally reproduce the issue and fix it in tinylog 2.5.0-M1.1 (see https://tinylog.org/v2/2022/03/update-for-first-milestone/).

Comment: Thanks for the fast support!
Everything worked, now it's very convenient